# How to Migrate VB 8 code (VS 2005) to VB 16 (VS 2019)

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a VB code project developed using VS 2005, (Vb8) and wanted to migrate the project using Visual Studio 2019 (VB 16 version). Please suggest the best possible way to do it.

Comment: You do know that VB.NET won't be supported into the future, right? ([it's not _dead_... but it is _done_](https://www.mrlacey.com/2020/03/vbnet-is-done-not-dead.html)) And that WebForms is on its last-legs? I don't think there's any value in spending time migrating to a stop-gap destination if you're doomed to rewrite everything in C# anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make sure the workflows and templates are installed (say vs2022), and then simple open the project.

You don't mention what version of .net the older project is based on, but in theory, you should with great success be able to open this project in vs 2019, or vs2022, and then be able to target framework 4.8 (the latest, or better stated last version of .net framework). You do not have a smooth upgrade to .net core, but you should be able to simple open the project. and set the framework to 4.8 and see if the project compiles/builds.

VERY but BEYOND very important?

You need to determine if this is a asp.net web site, or a asp.net web site application.
(look for a sln file in the project folder - if it has one, then you can/should be able to open that project using file->open project.

If no sln file exists, then use file->open web site, and browse to that folder.

Other then above (and making a mess if you don't figure out what kind of project), then updating to latest .net 4.8, and using vs2022 should work fine.

The code and application for the most part should work and run without issues.

But, find out what kind of application this is

(asp.net web site)

or
(asp.net web site application).

vs2019 is probably a "bit" better of a choice, since vs2019 is the LAST x32 bit version of VS. vs2022 is x64 bits now.

however, if your project works fine with vs2019, then you should be ok to upgrade to vs2022.

Since you ARE using vs2019, then I recommend you get the project working in vs2019, as it has better legacy x32 bit support.

However, I'm currently opening some rather old desktop, and some asp.net systems with vs2022, and they are working fine. Just remember to install all of the legacy templates and workflows in vs2019 BEFORE you try to open and start messing around.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback...it's Window service application